# Gradle script won't download dependencies

Tags: maven, android-studio, download, dependencies, build.gradle

I want to add a **library** in Android Studio **as dependency** to use it in my project.

I tried both adding the dependency via *Module Settings menu* and via direct input in *build.gradle-file* of the Module (s. [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HVGy.png)).

I also tried entering mavenCentral()-repository ([snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaCZN.png)) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671277/maven-dependencies-with-android-studio-gradle).

Building/synching the project with gradle is successful but org.apache.olingo lib never appears in log nor is added to my *lib folder* (or external libraries).

Of course I already tried refreshing the project tree-view (w/o success).

*Why* isn't the library downloaded (since I can search for the lib in the dependencies-add menu the internet access should be no barrier) and *how could I fix this issue*?

(As you may have realized, I'm a newbie in this environment - any hint might help)

Comment: Did you try to import a class from the library?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti : Yes, I did (see [this snapshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wamf6.png)).    

I also tried adding the .jars manually by downloading them and adding to dependencies (see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wUdwZ.png)) - this triggers a _Error:Gradle: duplicate files during packaging of APK_ and a  
> _Exec. failed for task ':app:packageDebug'._
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
> File 1: ...\app\libs\org.apache.olingo-olingo-odata2-core-2.0.4.jar
> File 2: ...\app\libs\org.apache.olingo-olingo-odata2-api-2.0.4.jar
.
Do you have any suggestions what to do next?

Comment: In the android block in the build.gradle add: packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'}

Comment: _Thanks to your hint_, I'm now able to use the .jar-files in my Project (i also added excludes for "META-INF/LICENSE" and "META-INF/NOTICE")!

This seems to be a good workaround for me in short term.  
Anyway, I would also like to know _which detail prevents me from loading the lib in my project automatically from maven repository_.

I would be thrilled if anyone could identify and fix the original issue.

Comment: Look very carefully what you type into `dependencies{}` block in your app's gradle file. One typo ruins everything. Double check. Also, take a look at `Messages` -> `Show console output` to see what exactly is happening wrong.