# How to use maven in android studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use [bottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) library in my project. When I add the proper `gradle` command in the `build.gradle` file and `sync`, I get this error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.0
```

I have searched a lot for the reason. A solution is to use jcenter(), but this is not accessible in my country and syncing lasts up to 1 or in some cases two hours. So I use maven instead. 
In this case how can I use the maven commands recommended on the library home page?
Where should I put the following code?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.roughike</groupId>
  <artifactId>bottom-bar</artifactId>
  <version>2.+</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16675271/3398732

Answer (score 1):

Gradle

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.+'
}
```

If error sync gradle run a proxy(`Host=127.0.0.1 , proxyPort=8580`) and type this command in cmd

```
gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8580
```

[image]

Comment: where should I put the maven in my prohect? is this a file?