# Add an android library to the default list of libraries in Studio/SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

So first of all, just to clear any doubts, i know how to add a library to an android project. My question here is that, i want to add a library to the list of default libraries in my android studio.

Let me explain with an example. Let's say i want to add the Glide library to my project. To do that firstly, i have to go to glide github page and then, from there i copy the `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'` text and paste in in my build.gradle file . Then the android studio would download the library over the internet. So every time i want to use the Glide library in any of my project, i have to do this. What i want , is that, i want to include a specific libary like Glide in my Default list of libraries that are available to me

[image]

So Here, is where i want to include my library project, so that i can use it, in any of my projects. Thanks in advance, for reading.

Comment: Have a look at Android Studio's Live Templates feature https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rI4tTd7-J8

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/39116613/1770868

Comment: @Luksprog, Firstly thank you for reading,  It is an alternate way of reusing code.

Comment: @ ahmad aghazadeh, This does not solve the problem though

Comment: Found [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/ae76870f096769f556c0fcb895dfc1327be0a578/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/structure/MavenDependencyLookupDialog.java) for the shown dialog, if this can be helpful for you.

Comment: @NickAsher Adding a library to a project is a line of code, isn't that what you want to do? The idea was to create a live template for the line 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:+' and assign it a shortcut(for example libGlide). Then in every project you could simply go to the gradle file, start typing libGlide and hit ENTER.

Comment: @Luksprog But can't i add the library to the default list directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid it is not so simple.

I looked at the newest Android Studio source code (branch `master`) and the code for this dialog ([`MavenDependencyLookupDialog.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/structure/gradle/MavenDependencyLookupDialog.java)). As you can see by looking at [this line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/structure/gradle/MavenDependencyLookupDialog.java#75) the dependencies are held inside `ImmutableList` and are **hardcoded**. There are held only not-support dependencies.

The support dependencies are held in different place ([`RepositoryUrlManager.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/templates/RepositoryUrlManager.java#117)). But they are also **hardcoded**.

You have three choices:

- Change module template as described in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39117074/6507689)
- Create a [Live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/live-templates.html) to automatically type `glide` and Intellij would give you a hint to insert glide dependency
- Change Android Studio source code, make a Pull Request and convince people responsible for it to make your changes into consideration.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to add the library to every new project/module automatically.
There is a folder with templates in the Android Studio directory. Look for:

```
..\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root
```

In this directory there is a file:

```
build.gradle.tfl
```

Modify it according to your needs.

Example:

```
dependencies {
    <#if dependencyList?? >
    <#list dependencyList as dependency>
    compile '${dependency}'
    </#list>
    </#if>
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
<#if WearprojectName?has_content && NumberOfEnabledFormFactors?has_content && NumberOfEnabledFormFactors gt 1 && Wearincluded>
    wearApp project(':${WearprojectName}')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
</#if>
<#if unitTestsSupported>
    testCompile 'junit:junit:${junitVersion}'
</#if>
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

As you can see, the Glide library has been added at the end.

When this file is modified, every new `Android Phone & Table module` will have this library included.

Of course there is nothing that prevents you from adding your own module or project template.

Comment: But, doing this adds the Glide Library or any library to all of my projects.

Comment: This was the first line of my answer. `Gilde` is added to every new project this way.