# Adding default dependencies to Gradle for all new projects

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am hooked on Butterknife (Jake Wharton, you are my hero) and would like to add this by default to the gradle configuration for all new projects that I create. I searched and cannot find where this is done in Android Studio (2.3).

Does someone know how to do this?

I know that I need to include this in my build.gradle (app-level):

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
   annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
  ...
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39287336/3137427

Comment: This answer worked for me. I suspect the edited template will be blown away upon the next update, but it did seem to work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603432/7589309